# Resetting variable with setter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty familiar with getters and setters in JavaScript, but I am little confused about the behavior I am currently getting.  Here is my code:

```
function u0(n) {

return {

    get count() { return ++n; },
    set count(m) { m = n; }

}

} 

v0 = u0(10); //start with 10
console.log(v0.count); //11: increase by 1
console.log(v0.count); //12: increase by 1
console.log(v0.count); //13: increase by 1
console.log(v0.count = 0); //set back to 0
console.log(v0.count); //14?
```

When I call the `count` method and set it, it does reset the count back to zero, but when I call my `count` method again without setting it, it picks up right where it left off.  I was under the impression that when I set the count method it sets `n` to `0`.

Why does `count` pick up where it left off instead of being reset back to `0` when I set `count`?

Comment: I don't see any `reset` attribute defined in your constructor function...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `v0.count = 0`?

Comment: @maerics Sorry about that!  I edited my question.  I got confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it backwards ;)

```
function u0(n) {
    return {
        get count() { return ++n; },
        set count(m) { n = m; } // Notice? ;)
    };
}
```

Comment: @SethenMaleno haha, it's ok, we all do this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a reset method. I think you want this:

```
v0.count = 0;
```

I bet your `v0` object looks like this now:

```
v0 = {
    n: 14,
    reset: 0
};
```

Also, it should be

```
set count(m) { n = m; } // you had them backwards
```